# How to run Laravel (Lumen) Scheduler on Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, lumen

I am new to running Laravel scheduler on Docker. So I find it difficult to run multiple commands (`php -S localhost:8000 -t public` and `php artisan schedule:work`) in the Dockerfile. Please help, what do I need to do to run scheduler successfully as I will also be moving it to AWS.

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apk --no-cache add \
php7 \
php7-mysqlnd \
php7-fpm \
php7-pdo \
php7-mbstring \
php7-xml \
php7-openssl \
php7-json \
php7-phar \
php7-zip \
php7-dom \
php7-session \
php7-zlib && \
php7 -r "copy('http://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
php7 composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer && \
php7 -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
ln -sf /usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/php && \
ln -s /etc/php7/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/php.ini

RUN set -x \
addgroup -g 82 -S www-data \
adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data

COPY . /src
ADD .env.example /src/.env
WORKDIR /src
RUN chmod -R 777 storage


RUN composer install

CMD php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently need another one Dockerfile with supervisord to run scheduler.

Using built-in php server for production is not recommended. So I suggest you to have 3 Dockerfiles

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
#...
```

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
# add conf file to fastcgi_pass to php container
```

```
FROM your-php-container:tag
RUN apk --no-cache add supervisor
# copy supervisor config file (with laravel scheduler ) to /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```